# FileNotFoundException - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
String f = getStringFromFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/PagamentoLio.json");



String getStringFromFile (String filePath)  {
    File fl = new File(filePath);
    FileInputStream fin = null;
    String error = "";
    try {
        fin = new FileInputStream(fl);

        String ret = convertStreamToString(fin);
        //Make sure you close all streams.
        fin.close();

        return ret;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
    }

    showMessageError(error);

    return "";
}
```

Mas quando ele chega na linha `fin = new FileInputStream(fl);` está lançando `FileNotFoundException`, o problema é que o arquivo existe e está no caminho correto. Tentei com outros arquivos e acontece a mesma coisa. O que pode  estar causando isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você declarou/pediu permissão para ler o armazenamento externo? Porque o próprio comentário indica que  a permissão foi negada

Comment: Acho que é isso mesmo que está faltando... vou tentar resolver. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ler ou gravar no armazenamento externo, é preciso solicitar a permissão.

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Para API Nível 23 (Android 6.0), é preciso solicitar a permissão em tempo de execução.

O código a seguir verifica se o aplicativo tem a permissão para ler os armazenamento externo do usuário e solicita a permissão, se necessário.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

        // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // Requisita a permissão

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                1000);
    }
}
```

Lida com a solicitação da permissão requerida

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1000: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting?hl=pt-BR

Comment: Vale lembrar que requestpermission é um método async, e também pode ser importante tratar quando o usuário clica em "dont ask again"

Comment: Bem lembrado @MurilloComino